# Value-of in won't show i XML file when transformed

Tags: c#, json, xml, xslt

I have a XSL file that looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/plain"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Fetch all products -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Data/Products" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Products">
    { "index":{"_index":"test-product", "_type":"Product"}}
    { "Id":"<xsl:value-of select="Id"/>",
 "name":"<xsl:value-of select="name"/>"
    "description":"<xsl:value-of select="description"/>",
    "Category 1":"<xsl:value-of select="cat1"/>",
 "Category 2":"<xsl:value-of select="cat2"/>",
 "Category 3":"<xsl:value-of select="cat3"/>",
 "Category 4":"<xsl:value-of select="cat4"/>" }
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when I run it in my XslCompiledTranform-method in VS, I don't get any values back in the .json result file.

```html
var myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
            myXslTrans.Load("Products.xsl");
            myXslTrans.Transform("Products.xml", "result_data_products.json");
```

Here is my XML file:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Products Id="1" name="Golf1" description="En langsom golf bil" cat1="Bil" cat2="VW" cat3="Golf" cat4="1" />
  <Products Id="2" name="Golf2" description="En knap så langsom golf bil. Faktisk er den næsten hurtig." cat1="Bil" cat2="VW" cat3="Golf" cat4="2" />
  <Products Id="3" name="Golf3" description="Det er ikke en golf. Det er et billede af en golf. Bil medfølger." cat1="Bil" cat2="VW" cat3="Golf" cat4="3" />
  <Products Id="4" name="Golf4" description="Den aller hurtigste bil. Hurtigere end en langsommere." cat1="Bil" cat2="VW" cat3="Golf" cat4="4" />
  <Products Id="5" name="7 jern" description="God kølle til tæsk og golf." cat1="Sport" cat2="Golf" cat3="Køller" cat4="" />
  <Products Id="6" name="19 jern" description="God til golf. Dårlig til tæsk." cat1="Sport" cat2="Golf" cat3="Køller" cat4="" />
  <Products Id="7" name="Golfbold" description="Rund golfbold" cat1="Sport" cat2="Golf" cat3="Bolde" cat4="Hvid" />
  <Products Id="8" name="Golfbold" description="Noget man slår til med sin kølle." cat1="Sport" cat2="Golf" cat3="Bolde" cat4="Sort" />
</Data>
```

And here is the result in .json format, where no value is inserted.

```html
    { "index":{"_index":"test-product", "_type":"Product"}}
    { "Id":"",
 "name":""
    "description":"",
    "Category 1":"",
 "Category 2":"",
 "Category 3":"",
 "Category 4":"" }
  
    { "index":{"_index":"test-product", "_type":"Product"}}
    { "Id":"",
 "name":""
    "description":"",
    "Category 1":"",
 "Category 2":"",
 "Category 3":"",
 "Category 4":"" }
  
    { "index":{"_index":"test-product", "_type":"Product"}}
    { "Id":"",
 "name":""
    "description":"",
    "Category 1":"",
 "Category 2":"",
 "Category 3":"",
 "Category 4":"" }
  
    { "index":{"_index":"test-product", "_type":"Product"}}
    { "Id":"",
 "name":""
    "description":"",
    "Category 1":"",
 "Category 2":"",
 "Category 3":"",
 "Category 4":"" }
  
    { "index":{"_index":"test-product", "_type":"Product"}}
    { "Id":"",
 "name":""
    "description":"",
    "Category 1":"",
 "Category 2":"",
 "Category 3":"",
 "Category 4":"" }
  
    { "index":{"_index":"test-product", "_type":"Product"}}
    { "Id":"",
 "name":""
    "description":"",
    "Category 1":"",
 "Category 2":"",
 "Category 3":"",
 "Category 4":"" }
  
    { "index":{"_index":"test-product", "_type":"Product"}}
    { "Id":"",
 "name":""
    "description":"",
    "Category 1":"",
 "Category 2":"",
 "Category 3":"",
 "Category 4":"" }
  
    { "index":{"_index":"test-product", "_type":"Product"}}
    { "Id":"",
 "name":""
    "description":"",
    "Category 1":"",
 "Category 2":"",
 "Category 3":"",
 "Category 4":"" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select attributes you need e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>` and not `<xsl:value-of select="Id"/>` so you need to change all those paths.